# this.state.messages is not a function

Tags: php, reactjs, map-function, rest

I am writing a chat app in react and rest-api in php. However I am getting a this.state.messages is not a function error. How can I fix this. I am still new at react and php, so thank you for your help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6GV5.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7DoZ.png)

This is how I get the data from rest-api and here is my code for rest-api

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET') {
    try {
        $query = $readDB->prepare('select id, username, text from tblmessages');
        $query->execute();
        $rowCount = $query->rowCount();
        $messageArray = array();

        while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $message = new Message($row['id'], $row['username'], $row['text']);
            $messageArray[] = $message->returnMessageAsArray();
        }

        $returnData = array();
        $returnData['rows_returned'] = $rowCount;
        $returnData['messages'] = $messageArray;

        $response = new Response();
        $response->setSuccess(true);
        $response->setHttpStatusCode(200);
        $response->toCache(true);
        $response->setData($returnData);
        $response->send();
        exit();
    }
    // ...
```

also here is the code for react

```
class MessagePanel extends Component {
    state = {
        messages: [],
    }

    componentDidMount = () => {
        axios.get('http://localhost:8888/restapi/messages')
            .then(response => {
                this.setState({messages: response.data});
                console.log(this.state.messages)
            })
    }
    
    sendMessage = (mes) => {
        const headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        }

        const data = {
            username: this.props.username,
            text: mes
        };

        axios.post('http://localhost:8888/restapi/messages', data, {
            headers: headers
        })
            .then(response => {

                console.log(response)
            })
    };
    
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="MessagePanel">

                <Layout/>

                <SidePanel users={this.state.usernames}/>

                <DisplayMessages messages={this.state.messages} username={this.props.username}/>


                <MessageBox sendMessage={this.sendMessage} username={this.props.username}/>


            </div>
        );
    }
}


render()
{
    return (
        <div className="DisplayMessage">
            <div className='message-container'>
                {this.props.messages.map(message => {
                    return (

                        <Message key={message.id} text={message.text} username={message.username}/>


                    )
                })}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
}

export default DisplayMessages;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bz6n.png)

Comment: What is the response are you getting when the component mounts at the code `console.log(this.state.messages)`

Comment: @jarivak 
When I delete the 
```
{this.props.messages.map(message => {
          return(

              <Message  key={message.id} text={message.text} username={message.username} />


          )
      })}

```
and run 
```console.log(this.state.messages)
```
I get this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6GV5.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7DoZ.png

if I don't delete the code and try to run, program crashes

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bz6n.png

Comment: I can see that the response from the backend is more nested, so try to replace this.setState({messages: response.data}); with this.setState({messages: response.data.data[0].messages});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see that the response from the backend is more nested, so try to replace

`this.setState({messages: response.data});`

with

`this.setState({messages: response.data.data[0].messages})`